# TextBlock stop reacting to data binding after changing Inlines

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My goal is having TextBox over TextBlock which upon finished typing changes its Inlines in order to colorize certain keywords.

My control xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               Foreground="AliceBlue"
               FontFamily="Consolas"
               Name="MyTextBlock"/>

    <TextBox AcceptsTab="True"
             AcceptsReturn="True" 
             TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
             Foreground="Transparent"
             Background="Transparent"
             Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             TextChanged="OnTextChanged"
             PreviewKeyDown="OnPreviewKeyDown"
             Name="MyTextBox"/>
</Grid>
```

Part of code that is problematic:

```
private void HandleFinishedTypingEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Timer is being used for end typing detection
    (sender as Timer).Stop();

    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var inlines = MyTextBlock.Inlines;
        inlines.Clear();

        Run run;

        foreach (string word in Text.Split(' '))
        {
            run = new Run(word + " ");
            if (word == "keyword")
            {
                 run.Foreground = Brushes.Lime;
                 inlines.Add(run);
            }
            else
            {
                 run.Foreground = Brushes.AliceBlue;
                 inlines.Add(run);
            }
         }
    });
}
```

The code itself work but after that TextBlock doesn't update by property change, only when code updating Inlines runs.

Comment: As soon as you set the Inlines property, the Text Binding is ignored. You should not be using both properties at the same time. As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in a OneWay Binding is pointless. It only has an effect in TwoWay or OnewayToSource Bindings.